# Using count on three different columns with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i am trying to **count** sub_tag_1,sub_tag_2,sub_tag_3 columns only when **where** condition is true and in the last i want **sum** of all three columns as a result.

here is my virtual table :

```
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id| sub_tag_1 | sub_tag_2 | sub_tag_3 |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1 |   php     |           |           |
| 2 |   mysql   |     php   |           |
| 3 |   java    |           |     php   |
+---+-----------+---------+-------------+
```

i already try so many times but i failed every time and here my sql query:

```
1) SELECT count(`sub_tag_1`) AND count(`sub_tag_2`) AND count(`sub_tag_3`) 
FROM posts where `sub_tag_1` 
LIKE "php" and `sub_tag_2` LIKE "php" and `sub_tag_3` LIKE "php";
```

above query executed successfully but it didn't match any thing in database and it **return 0**

```
2) SELECT count(`sub_tag_1`) AND count(`sub_tag_2`) AND count(`sub_tag_3`) 
FROM posts where `sub_tag_1` = "php" and `sub_tag_2` = "php" 
and `sub_tag_3` = "php" 
and sum(count(`sub_tag_1`)+count(`sub_tag_2`)+count(`sub_tag_3`));
```

above query give me **error: Invalid use of group function**

Please advice and explain step by step how can i do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a confition in the `WHERE` clause will give you all the rows that have `php` in all three columns. Since there are none, you'll get the result `0`.

What you're trying to do is retreive **all** the rows and only count the appropriate values. This can be done by using a `CASE` clause for each column, in the following fashion:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE sub_tag_1 WHEN 'php' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS subg_tag_1_count, 
       SUM(CASE sub_tag_2 WHEN 'php' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS subg_tag_2_count, 
       SUM(CASE sub_tag_3 WHEN 'php' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS subg_tag_3_count
FROM   my_table
WHERE  'php' IN (sub_tag_1, sub_tag_2, sub_tag_3)
```